# My App does not qualify for use of the requested permissions (SMS) Google new policy (Ionic 3)

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

We reviewed your request and found that your app, does not qualify for use of the requested permissions for the following reasons:

The declared feature `{Default SMS}` is allowed; however we determined it to be unnecessary for the core functionality of your app.

```
Default SMS [READ_SMS, SEND_SMS, WRITE_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS, RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH, RECEIVE_MMS]
```

I use the  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`
to share the app via SMS (send a text and a link to the website ), whats the work arround?
Thanks

Comment: Sharing the app via SMS means sending the `GooglePlay` link of your app in SMS right?

Comment: @KavinPrabhu it send a text and a link to the website

Comment: Then you can achieve that via `ImplicitIntent` itself right? Rather than you sending the message from your application you can invoke the app in the device which can do it!

Comment: @KavinPrabhu yes i see your point here , but im using ionic 3 , i will try to make a bridge  thanks

Comment: I believe that shouldn't be a problem, refer https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/web-intent/ this may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want SMS as a feature but not a requirement.

I think what you wanted to do is add uses-feature declarations with `android:required="false"`.

From [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#permissions-features)

> When you declare `android:required="false"` for a feature, it means that the application prefers to use the feature if present on the device, but that it is designed to function without the specified feature, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`

and calling a intent to open the Native Device Sms App